# How should we protect the paws of our dog when going to mountains in winter?

Tags: dogs

we are planning a weekend in the mountains in winter. There will be snow and it will be very cold (below 0C). What I remember from last time, our dog was freezing and we had a jacket to protect her from the cold. But for the paws I am not sure, what do you think should be used to make her enjoy the snow (longer) ?
Thanks!

Comment: Very cold is a wide phrase :) strongly depending of country and climate. Good that you wrote the degrees additional. Instead I would have assumed lower than -10 degrees ;)

Comment: What breed is your dog?

Comment: it is a maltese bichon, and it will be below 10C in the mountains I checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the dogs would not need much protection, if the ground is dry. They actually become frantic when given the opportunity to play in fresh snow.

But there are cases when some protection might be needed. As strange as it might sound, there are "[**shoes for dogs**](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-e&q=shoes%20for%20dogs)". Just try to find some in your area. They might even come with winter-design for extra-comfort.

I wish you to have fun in the mountains.

Comment: thanks, we had some walk in the snow area last weekend, it looks like snow shoes might help. i have ordered some, hopefully these will fit our small dogs paws. what about paw care creak?

Comment: small note, i got the shoes and put it onto our dog... she refused to walk with the shoes, then I have put 1 shoe, and tried again, she at least tried to walk but it looks like it will need quite a bit more training until she will accept to walk with all 4 shoes.

Comment: well, I never said that the dog will happy from moment zero wearing those shoes :) But good luck with the training.